# "sync" or replicate between tables

Tags: sql, synchronization, between, replicate

I have a existing table "dbo.Source Table" and I want to make another one `[me].[DestinationTable]` in which to copy some columns from existing table "dbo.Source Table". I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

This is what I want, in table "dbo.Source Tabel" I have one row in that I have information in columns "TextColumn", "ValueColumn" etc. For start this information I want to be copied into new table `[me].[Destination Table]`, but when information into table "dbo.Source Tabel" for example in column "TextColumn" change from "MDO" with "Marius", to update automatically in table `[me].[Destination Table]` and so on for each column and when a row is deleted from dbo.SourceTable, to be deleted and from me.DestinationTable.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SourceTable
    (
    SourcePrimaryKeyID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    TextColumn VARCHAR(2048),
    ValueColumn DECIMAL(18,3),
    NumberColumn INT
    )

CREATE TABLE [me].[DestinationTable]
    (
    DestinationPrimaryKeyID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    SourcePrimaryKeyID INT,
    TextColumn VARCHAR(2048),
    ValueColumn DECIMAL(18,3),
    NumberColumn INT,
    ActionType VARCHAR(100),
    CreatedDate AS GETDATE(), -- Default to current date
    CreatedDatabaseUser AS SUSER_SNAME()
    )

GO
```

Comment: Do you need to check all columns? Or just some of them?

Comment: I nead to check and update only column that I copy to DestinationTabel from Source tabe.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a envorionment to test it but:

```
MERGE me.DestinationTable tgt
USING dbo.SourceTable src
 ON  src.SourcePrimaryKeyID = tgt.DestinationPrimaryKeyID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    tgt.TextColumn =   src.TextColumn, 
    tgt.ValueColumn =  src.ValueColumn,
    tgt.NumberColumn = src.NumberColumn
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT VALUES (
  src.TextColumn, 
  src.ValueColumn,
  src.NumberColumn
);
GO
```

Comment: I make new Query and copy into what you wrote above? I do that and say "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'DestinationPrimaryKeyID'."

Comment: Very Sorry: src.SourcePrimaryKeyID = tgt.DestinationPrimaryKeyID. My mistake

Comment: q4za4...I tested and it works. The only "problem" is that for each update of table "me.Destination Table" I must press F5, cannot be done automatically?
And can not that the code check and update just some columns in SourceTable ?? I tried to delete your code "tgt.NumberColumn = src.NumberColumn" and "src.NumberColumn" but it does not work and I am giving this error "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'. ". Thanks a lot.

Comment: i assumed You deleted tgt.NumberColumn = src.NumberColumn but mayby forgot about the coma after  tgt.ValueColumn =  src.ValueColumn, <--

About this F5: first time i hear about pressing f5 after update. This statement is meant to "do" all rows. 
Updated answer

Comment: I deleted coma after tgt.Value Column = src.Value Column and still don't work.
regarding F5 I mean that that when change value in table dbo.SourceTable doesn't update automatically and I must press buton "Execute".

Comment: Ooo I forgotten, to tell this and when a row is deleted from dbo.SourceTable, to be deleted and from me.DestinationTable.

Comment: It is possible to copy and update(even the rows deleted) for more than two table?

Comment: No one, no idea?